# I face database connection error when I try to connect data base with the latest version of PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection, smarty

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()
show this errror:

```
// returns true or false
function _pconnect($argHostname, $argUsername, $argPassword, $argDatabasename)
{
    if (ADODB_PHPVER >= 0x4300)
        $this->_connectionID = mysql_pconnect($argHostname,$argUsername,$argPassword,$this->clientFlags);
    else
        $this->_connectionID = mysql_pconnect($argHostname,$argUsername,$argPassword);
    if ($this->_connectionID === false) return false;
    if ($this->autoRollback) $this->RollbackTrans();
    if ($argDatabasename) return $this->SelectDB($argDatabasename);
    return true;    
}
```

show error in mysql_connect ()
so how to fix this and how to remove deprecation in the latest version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

n PHP5.6 or higher versions, mysql_ functions are totally removed. 
Try PDO.
or read this one: [mysqli doc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)